# How to create a 'pipe' mesh from a doodle on paper

Tags: modeling, mesh

Would love some advice..

I'm importing an SVG scan of a squiggle on paper, which comes into Blender fine. I've managed to extrude it so that it's a 3D mesh instead of a flat plane. But when I try and bevel it to turn it into a 'pipe' and round everything off so it's no longer flat, it doesn't work - nothing happens.

[image]

My overall aim is to create a 3D sculpture of my paper squiggles, but as if someone had created gold pipe work. So the extruded result is too 'flat'. I want spaghetti, not tagliatelli!

thanks

Comment: if you bevel this kind of topology some faces will overlap, first try X > Limited Dissolve, but I'm not sure it will fix the problem, you'll probably still need to give some corrections, it also depends on how large is your bevel

Comment: Why not apply a bevel to the curve before you convert it?

Comment: Thanks all. The bevel is my attempt at 'rounding off' the mesh so it becomes a circular pipe shape, rather than a squashed pipe shape. So bevelling before conversion will only smooth the profile won't it?

Comment: Anyone have any ideas about this? The Bevelling modifier does nothing to this mesh at all.